# Assembly fails to load via COM interop unless framework 3.5 is present?

Tags: c#, com, vb6, com-interop, .net-framework-version

I have a VB6 application that uses a C# COM DLL compiled with .Net Framework 3.5.  However, on Server 2016, .Net 3.5 is not installed.   However, 4.6.7 is, and will run the DLL's code.

However, when vb6 called `CreateObject`, it fails. (though the the COM object is registered properly.)

The application installer calls the RegASM utility in the correct .Net framework folder to register the type Library for the DLL. I can verify that all the correct registry entries are made.

The VB6 app fails with Error 429: Cannot create object. If I do nothing else but install .Net 3.5, it works. So, I'm sure the registration is fine. **I just don't know how to make the DLL use the 4.x.x framework.**

I tried creating `VB6App.exe.config` and putting the `supportedRuntime` tags in it.  No luck -- presume this only works for .Net exes.

The .Net COM DLL is targeted at both new and old OS.

I'd rather not install .Net 3.5 if I don't have to.    Is there a way to make this work?

```
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <!--Will run on .Net 2.0,3.5-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <!--Will run on .Net 4.0 and later-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Hmm also you mentioned that "4.6.7 will run the DLL's code" - how have you confirmed this? Do you have a separate .NET-only app which uses the same assembly, for instance?

Comment: Could that be a x86 vs x64 issue? VB6 is x86, are you sure you registered your COM object in the x86 registry? Otherwise you can use Process Monitor tool from sysinternals and look at the registry/file calls.

Comment: No,  it is not an x86 vs. x64 issue.  This is a long established app and DLL set.  Vb6 app and DLL deployed on 100s of x86 and  x64 systems.   The new. Factor here is latest WIn 10 and server 2016, where no 3.5 is installed by default.  The question really is:  Does a app.exe.config file work on non managed exe when loading managed DLLs?  Or, is there a different solution?

Comment: Found this old answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/57caf5b1-788b-445c-885a-fff71c62394e/appconfig-with-unmanaged-exes?forum=clr.  It answers an important question: can app.confg files be used on non-managed exes.  Still trying to figure this out.

Comment: attribute useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" solved the problem`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <!--Will run on .Net 2.0,3.5-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    <!--Will run on .Net 4.0 and later-->
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
`